# disable iPhone full screen video

Tags: iphone, ios, video, fullscreen, mobile-safari

I'm trying to watch a web presentation (passworded, can't provide a live link) arranged like this:
[image: web page mockup with 3 panes: video, notes, slideshow]
When I view the site on an iPhone, Safari "helpfully" zooms the video to full screen, covering the rest of the page (which I want to see).

I tried [the pinch gesture](https://iphone-tricks.com/tutorial/5419-safari-play-videos-without-full-screen-mode), but whenever I do that, the page interprets the touch as a pause click. Then when I hit play again, the video zooms back to full screen. Repeat ad nauseam.

Is there a way to disable the video zoom feature entirely? Alternately, is there a 3rd party browser that doesn't have the video zoom feature?

Comment: Which 3rd party browsers have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to disable video zoom.

Puffin browser does not have video zoom and can be used as an alternative.

[Link to app.](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/puffin-web-browser/id472937654?mt=8)

Example:

[image: example]

Notice how the video is not in full screen.